# Matching source Excel records to SSMS records

Tags: sql-server, excel

For some context: I work as a program manager at a not-for-profit community hospital. We have extremely limited experienced database resources available, so I'd love to figure this one out on my own instead of having to wait. Please forgive my naivety. This is also my first Stack Overflow post, so thank you in advance for your patience.

On a monthly basis, I am provided an Excel file from a business partner that is a list of members. Each row is a person, and the columns are MemberID, LastName, FirstName, and DateOfBirth.

In our medical records database, which we query with SSMS, the primary identifier for patients is PatientID (from the Person table). Fortunately (I think), also in the Person table are the fields LastName, FirstName, and DateOfBirth.

Is it possible to use the LastName, FirstName, and DateOfBirth fields from the Excel file to somehow "match" to PatientIDs from the Person table in our medical records database?

If I can figure this out - essentially translation of the list of LastName, FirstName, and DateOfBirth provided by the source into a list of PatientIDs from our database - I'll be able to write a SELECT statement that gives me the data I need.

Thanks again in advance!

Comment: Load the Excel data into a working table in your database and join on your matching criteria.